# How to delete garbage characters from input in C

Tags: c, validation, input

I have a piece a code that works for input validation, I need a little bit more explanation for why it works. The line where the garbage variable reads a character from getchar and checks to see if it's not equal EOF confuses me a little. It's purpose is to read the garbage input from the user, and allow the user to re-enter the input. My question is, how exactly does this line work?

```
  int steps = 0;                                                
  int true;                                                 
  int garbage;                                              

printf("Enter the integer increment number in the range ");  
printf("of[%d - %d]: ", minInput, maxInput);
true = scanf("%d", &steps);

/* INPUT VALIDATION */

while (!true || isdigit(steps) ||(steps < minInput || steps > maxInput) ){  
    while ((garbage = getchar()) != EOF && garbage != '\n') {                   
    } // end while;

    printf("Invalid input... please enter a number in the range ");
    printf("of[%d - %d]: ", minInput, maxInput);
    true = scanf("%d", &steps);

}// end while
```

Comment: The `isdigit(steps)` is the very first thing I see that has questionable logic. It was never read as a character (`%c`) it was read as integer decimal (`%d`). All that function does is test a character for membership in `'0'...'9'`. The values `0..9` (integer values; not characters) will *never* result in `isdigit(steps)` being true, so it is pointless in your conditional.

Comment: `true` is a rather ill-advised variable name - it normally refers to a value not a variable, and will conflict with the `stdbool.h` definition of the symbol and precludes C++ compilation.

Comment: When `scanf("%d", &steps)` returns `EOF`, `while (...) { }` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf()` call with the `%d` format specifier will retrieve only decimal digit characters, and will stop interpreting input at the first non-digit character.  However it will not normally return at all until a complete line is buffered, so there will be at least a newline buffered and possibly other non-digit characters.

The:

```
while ((garbage = getchar()) != EOF && garbage != '\n')
```

statement reads all buffered characters until the end of the line or EOF.  While it is perhaps unusual for the console input stream to issue an "end-of-file", the stdin stream can be redirected from a file and need not refer to the console input. An EOF may be inserted into the console input stream via a platform dependent CTRL code, and when redirected from a file, if the file contained a line without a newline, the loop would not terminate.

The use of `isdigit(steps)` is incorrect - `steps` is an integer value and `isdigit()` tests a *single* character value to determine whether it represents a decimal digit.  `steps` is implicitly a valid value by virtue of the `true` being non-zero and the `%d` format specifier, so if the intent is to determine a number was entered that is what `true` is for.

Comment: "steps is implicitly a valid value by virtue of the true being non-zero" --> This is true when `true == 1`  .  It is incorrect when `true == EOF` and then `steps` is untouched or indeterminate.  Both `1` and `EOF` are non-zero.